# Gitweb look and feel

Tags: theming, gitweb

I've recently installed git with Gitweb. Gitweb seems like a nice simple interface which does just what we need it to do. Problem is it looks very ugly. It looks as if it's just a cgi script with a static folder containing all the css and images.

I was thinking of tinkering with the css and cgi script to see how I could change the appearance of it. I wanted to know if anyone has had experience with doing the same and how did you go?

Alternatively does anyone know of any nice alternative Gitweb solutions that I can dload and hook up to my git?

Comment: have a look: https://github.com/kogakure/gitweb-theme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit gitweb style by editing his files in `/usr/share/gitweb`
List of the files :

- gitweb.cgi
- static/gitweb.css
- static/gitweb.js
- static/git-logo.png
- static/git-favicon.png

You can also searched for themes like [this one](https://github.com/kogakure/gitweb-theme) for more themes there is Google

Answer (score 0):

How about [Gitblit](http://www.gitblit.com)?  It has a Gitweb feel.